# Can you roll a critical failure on a single action where you roll multiple skill dice?

Tags: savage-worlds, fumbles

A normal Trait roll involves only 2 dice for a Wild Card, and thus the rule for Critical Failures is described as:

> snake-eyes (double 1s) on one of these rolls is a critical failure
>   (SW Deluxe 63)

But there are circumstances where you roll multiple Trait die with only one Wild Die (full-auto fire, wild swing, etc.). Can these end up as a Critical Fail?

Possible options I came up with:

- No CF (seems RAW, but not RAI and no fun either)
- CF only on full-1 rolls (not really logical)
- CF if WD+1 rolls 1, affects the whole action
- CF if WD+1 rolls 1, affects only 1 shot/swing/...

Is there a mention of this in any official material?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

It is entirely possible to roll multiple Critical Fails in these circumstances. If you roll a 1 on the Wild Die, then each 1 you roll on the Skill Dice counts as an individual Critical Fail.

See [here](http://archive.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=51122&p=455051&hilit=critical%20fail#p455051) for official confirmation of this.

Comment: He made that post over a *decade* ago. Has it not shown up in any book or errata?

Comment: That was just the first example I found. It's something that comes up reasonably regularly on the forums and Google+. I'm not aware of any changes to the books to reflect it though.